# How to place styles in separate .xaml files

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have an application with a large number of styles that are currently duplicated in the .xaml for each window of the application. I would like to be able to reference one file called UiStyles.xaml that contains all of the styles for the application.

After reading a ton of answered questions on here and Google I've tried this:

ButtonStyle.xaml:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="ButtonStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="48"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

UiStyles.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ButtonStyle.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <Style TargetType="Control" /> <!-- Added this based on other user's suggestions to account for .net 4 bug -->
</ResourceDictionary>
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TestingGround.UI.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/UIStyles.xaml"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Content="Test Text"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But my button style is not being applied! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note when you apply a key to a style, you have to explicitly apply it to the control so

```
<Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" 
        Content="Test Text"
        Style={StaticResource ButtonStyle} />
```

However if you want all buttons to default to the style  remove the `x:key="ButtonStyle"`.

```
<Style TargetType="...">
```

Answer (score 4):

You have created your button style with an x:Key, but are not referencing that in your button instance.

You need to set the "Style" property of the button like so:

```
<Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Content="Test Text"/>
```